Website timeout issue when running two identical background services .NET Core
I am running two identical background services, their only job is to pull from azure sub and send to API. I am pasting one below for the other one only the name changes and values for apiUrl, _topicName, and _subscriptionName.
Startup.cs
services.AddHostedService<WhatsAppService>();
services.AddHostedService<CreateInvoiceService>(); // As soon as added the site starts
throwing timeout even though nothing is on azure sub.

Service class:
public class WhatsAppService : BackgroundService
{
    private string _apiUrl = "";
    private readonly AzureServiceBusConnection _azureServiceBusConnection;
    private readonly WhatsAppSettings _whatsappsettings;
    private ServiceBusClient _client;
    private string _topicName = "";
    private string _subscriptionName = "";
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _throttle;

    public WhatsAppService(IOptions<AzureServiceBusConnection> azureServiceBusConnection, IOptions<WhatsAppSettings> whatsappsettings)
    {
        _throttle = new SemaphoreSlim(10);  // Allows up to 10 concurrent requests

        _azureServiceBusConnection = azureServiceBusConnection.Value;
        _whatsappsettings = whatsappsettings.Value;

        _apiUrl = _whatsappsettings.ApiUrl;
        _topicName = _whatsappsettings.TopicName;
        _subscriptionName = _whatsappsettings.SubscriptionName;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _client = new ServiceBusClient(_azureServiceBusConnection.ConnectionString);
        var sessionTasks = new List<Task>(); // List to track session processing tasks

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceBusSessionReceiver sessionReceiver = null;

                try
                {
                    sessionReceiver = await _client.AcceptNextSessionAsync(_topicName, _subscriptionName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error accepting session: {ex.Message}");
                    await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); // Wait before retrying
                    continue; // Retry accepting the next session
                }

                if (sessionReceiver != null)
                {
                    // Start processing messages for this session in a new task
                    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Processing messages for session: {sessionReceiver.SessionId}");

                        while (true)
                        {
                            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = await sessionReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                            if (message == null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No more messages in this session.");
                                break; // Exit the inner loop if no more messages are available
                            }

                            var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
                            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {messageBody}");

                            var success = await SendDataToApiAsync(messageBody);
                            if (!success)
                            {
                                await sessionReceiver.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await sessionReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
                            }
                        }

                        await sessionReceiver.CloseAsync();
                    });

                    sessionTasks.Add(task); // Track the task for this session
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No sessions available to process.");
                }

                // Clean up completed tasks to avoid memory leaks
                sessionTasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);

                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken); // Wait before checking for the next session
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> SendDataToApiAsync(string message)
    {
        await _throttle.WaitAsync();  // Wait to enter the semaphore
        try
        {
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            try
            {
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_apiUrl, content);
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HTTP Request failed: {e.Message}");
                return false;  // Log and handle HTTP request errors appropriately
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _throttle.Release();  // Ensure semaphore is always released
        }
    }
}

What could be possible reason for this, I know I can put them both in one but again want to know if there is something wrong with the current flow or its just resources?
Thank you

It sounds like running two identical background services is causing timeout issues. Could you share more about the environment they're running in and any specific error logs? Have you tried debugging to see if there's a bottleneck, like connection limits or resource contention? Checking with breakpoints or logging could help narrow down if it's related to API response times or server resources.
One possible issue could be that each BackgroundService is opening a new ServiceBusClient connection. Instead of separate connections, try using a shared ServiceBusClient by registering it as a singleton in Startup.cs. High concurrency settings with SemaphoreSlim (currently set to 10) may also cause contention; reducing this number or adding a retry mechanism could help. Additionally, avoid recreating HttpClient for each request, as this can lead to socket exhaustion—consider making HttpClient a singleton or using IHttpClientFactory. Lastly, check server resources like CPU and memory usage; running two services might be overloading the environment.
Let me know if that helps.

The services did not perform any actions as they were not loading anything they were hitting azure to get but then nothing and repeat. So is confusing why it happened is there some resource to follow?
